# Euler-Lagrange Equation, $\dot{P_{\alpha}}\neq\partial_{q_{\alpha}}L$

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws

We know
\begin{equation}
\frac{d(\partial_{\dot{q}_{\alpha}}T) }{dt}=\partial_{q_{\alpha}}(T-U) 
\\
\partial_{\dot{q}_{\alpha}}U=0
\rightarrow\dot{P_{\alpha}}=\partial_{q_{\alpha}}L
\end{equation}
This holds only when the first statement of the second line is true, otherwise
\begin{equation}
\dot{P_{\alpha}}=\partial_{q_{\alpha}}T
\end{equation}
This is really important when talking about simmetrie, as:
\begin{equation}
\dot{P_{\alpha} }=\partial_{q_{\alpha}}L=0 \rightarrow P_{\alpha}=\partial_{\dot{q_{\alpha}}}L=constant
\end{equation}
While the first member changes from L to T, the second one remains with L.


When does this happen?

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE. Could you please provide more info about what you are studying? Perhaps a source or something like that?

Comment: Actually studying physics. I don't have a source for the first line. If you need one I will write the equation from scratch without any problem

Comment: No, I think it is pretty much self contained, but it does require that me assuming what you mean by some symbols, which is sometimes not good. So, try to explain what you mean with the symbols you are using that are not too obvious:)

Comment: T is kinetik energy, U is potential energy, L is Lagrangian, $\partial$ is partial derivative, q is a generalised coordinate, p is a generalised momentum, $\alpha$ is the index.